# Are questions about institutions within scope of our site?

Tags: discussion

We received our first question about specific institutions today: [A fair comparison of premium institutes of India like IIT’ and IISC with the world renowned universities like Oxford and Cambridge](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7952/a-fair-comparison-of-premium-institutes-of-india-like-iit-and-iisc-with-the-wor)

Is such a question topical here?  My first instinct is that we are unlikely to find the expertise here that OP is requesting, and while that leads me to expect little engagement with the question. However, traffic is not a substitute for topicality, and is not a basis for determining topicality.

The current wording of our topics meta page (https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) seems to indicate that the question is strictly out of bounds.  However, that page seems a bit out-of-date, as a substantial portion of our questions are on topics that are of interest to CS educators, but not strictly about how to teach concepts.  We seem to have settled into something more akin to "is this of interest to educators", which suggest that we should revisit our topics meta page.

In the mean time, however, is this question topical?  Is it of interest to educators?  The schools in question see many thousands of students, so they are not small concerns, but the question nevertheless feels niche.

How do others in the community feel about it?

Comment: Interestingly, OP deleted the question.  I will nevertheless leave this meta post up in case a similar issue comes up in the future.